# My image is laying on top of my text

Tags: swift, uiimageview, constraints, wkwebview

[image: Image of what it currently looks like]

I am trying to style my image and my text. I was able to center the image on the top. But I can't get the text to go under the image. I have included my code. I am trying to do the constraints programatically.

```
class LadyDetailViewController: UIViewController {
    var webView: WKWebView!
    var detailItem: [String: String]!

    override func loadView() {
        webView = WKWebView()
        view = webView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //add image
        let image:UIImage = UIImage(named: detailItem["image"]!)!

        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        self.view.addSubview(imageView)

        //image constraints
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

        imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor,constant: 108).isActive = true

        //share information with others
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .action, target: self, action: #selector(shareTapped))

        guard detailItem != nil else {return}

        let name = detailItem["name"]

        if let body = detailItem["body"] {
            var html = "<html>"
            html += "<head>"
            html += "<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">"
            html += "<style> body { font-size: 150%; font-family: \"Palatino Linotype\", \"Book Antiqua\", Palatino, serif;} </style>"
            html += "</head>"
            html += "<body bgcolor=\"#eeebda\">"
            html += "<h2><font color = \"#001547\">"
            html += name!
            html += "</font> </h2>"
            html += "<font color = \"#140911\">"
            html += body
            html += "</font>"
            html += "</body>"
            html += "</html>"

            webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
        }
    }

    @objc func shareTapped() {
        let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [detailItem["name"]!,detailItem["body"]!], applicationActivities: [])
        vc.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem
        present(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Do u want that image to lie between Ada love and the remaining text?

Comment: It is not a label. the text is all from a JSON file that I am adding to the view using html

Comment: Would it make sense to add individual labels for the text?

Comment: Make Ada love as a separate label. So that u can set constraints easily

Comment: Thanks I will try that.